# What is the meaning of "unchanged to" in the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I could not figure out what the meaning of the sentence?

> In this case, the analysis **applies unchanged to** the worst-case ratios of the lengths of shortest grid paths and shortest paths.

what is the meaning of "applies unchanged to"?

Comment: Firstly, do you understand the basic definitions of "[apply](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apply)" and "[unchanged](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/unchanged)"?  If you have looked those up, can you re-phrase the sentence in a way that makes sense to you?

Comment: @stangdon  Is this rephrase correct? "In this time, the anaysis carry out identically the worst-case ratios of the lenghts of shortest grid paths and shortest paths."

Comment: The more I keep reading this, the more I feel the word "as" is needed between *unchanged* and *to*. That is probably my problem, though :)

Comment: @lurker - No, "as" is unnecessary and would make it confusing.  It's just a split infinitive: *the analysis applies to the ratios*.  How does it apply to them?  *it applies **unchanged** to them.*  You wouldn't say "the analysis applies as to the ratios."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a rewrite that should clarify the meaning:

> In this case, the *same analysis could be applied* to the worst-case
>   ratios of the lengths of shortest grid paths and shortest paths.